# Initializing Performance Counter Monitor control registers on a CPU

Tags: x86, operating-system, cpu-architecture, performancecounter

Does anyone know what module is responsible for initializing performance counter monitor (PCM) control registers on an x86 CPU? Is it done by the hardware on reset or is it done by the bootloader or some other kernel module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance Monitor Counters (PMCs) don't need to be initialized, they need to be programmed (or set) when the software want to use the feature.

The CPU don't do anything to the PMCs after a reset, at least nothing architecturally visible (i.e. visible to the programmers).

The bootloader doesn't deal with such things.

It is a kernel module that handlea the PMCs because they are Model Specific Registers (MSRs) that can only be accessed with instructions (like `rdmsr`, `wrmsr`) that are privileged (i.e. they need the code to run in kernel space).
The kernel module can then expose the functionality to user-space programs either through the OS interfaces or by allowing the instruction `rdpmc` to be executed by unprivileged code (though it only allow reading the already preset counters).

---

To learn more about PMCs, see [Intel Manual 3B, Chapter 18](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3b-part-2-manual.html).

Comment: IIRC, the kernel can enable direct user-space access to the perf counters.  (i.e. set things up so the [RDPMC instruction](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/RDPMC.html) works in user-space)

Comment: @PeterCordes If I'm not wrong, user-space programs can only use `rdpmc` for reading. But it's worth mentioning, thanks!

Comment: I haven't used RDPMC manually, but yes I think it's only for reading the actual counters.  To select what you want them to count, I think you need WRMSR.  Still, that's sufficient for very low overhead measurement, lower than even RDTSC.  (And you can count core clock cycles, not wall-clock reference cycles.)